# Numpy: nanargmin select indice of 0 if row contains all NaN

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following matrix:

```
matrix = np.array([[0,np.nan,1],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[1,2,3]])
```

I would like to obtain an array of min row values. In the case that a row contains all nan values, that indice for that row of all nan values should be 0. The reslting array should be.

```
array([0,0,0])
```

If I try to use `np.argmin(matrix,axis=1)` then the min indice is where np.nan occurs e.g:

```
array([1, 0, 0])
```

This is not desired, and if I use `np.nanargmin(matrix,axis=1)` I get `raise ValueError("All-NaN slice encountered")`

Comment: What would be the result for `matrix = np.array([[1,np.nan,0],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[1,2,3]])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill the NaNs with infinity using [`numpy.nan_to_num`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html), then get the `argmin`:

```
np.argmin(np.nan_to_num(matrix, nan=float('inf')), axis=1)
```

output: `array([0, 0, 0])`

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your array into a masked array, where all np.nans are masked and then get the argmin of that array:

```
np.ma.masked_invalid(matrix).argmin(axis=1)
```

output: `array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)`